# Core Data Custom Objects and Entities in Swift

Tags: core-data, swift, save, loading, relationships

I've tried to find the answer to this in pre-answered questions but I've been having trouble putting it all together, so hopefully you can help. I'm writing an app that deals with two custom objects, the workout class and the exercise class. I should mention this is in Swift.

```
class Workout : NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var workoutList : [Exercise]

@NSManaged var title : String

}
```

and

```
class Exercise {

var reps = 0
var sets = 0
var description = ""
var title = ""

init(reps: Int, sets: Int, title: String ){
    self.reps = reps
    self.sets = sets
    self.title = title
}
```

}

I'm trying to come up with the best way to save these locally using core data. I would ideally like to be able to save a workout object, which has an array with references to all the specific exercises in that workout. I would then like to be able to load that specific object at will.  I've considered using relationships between the two classes, but honestly I don't understand them well enough to know how to use them correctly. Looking at this, what is the best way to save these custom classes so they will work as I've described?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the basic data types supported directly by Core Data, such as strings, integers, booleans, etc., all your custom classes must be Core Data entities. This means that the `Exercise` class must also be a `NSManagedObject` subclass, and the `workoutList` property must be a relationship between the `Workout` and `Exercise` entities (represented in Swift/ObjC by classes).

Comment: I see, so the entity can be thought of as a class. That makes more sense. Are you suggesting that I rid myself of the workoutList property in swift, and instead add a relationship between the two entities in the code data file? Or add the relationship on top of what I've already done?

Comment: One to one relationships in code are also represented as properties. It's just the backing store that behaves differently. I suggesting a good tutorial on Core Data entities and relationships.